# navigationItem.set_BarButton does not work - swift

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchbar, uinavigationitem

I am implementing a hidden search bar.

Everything works fine, except the commands which ment to bring back the bar buttons, in the function which hides the search bar.

Also, UISearchBar.showCancelButton does not work too, so I had to implement the cancel button manually. (I have set the delegate for the search bar to self)

Here is the code:

```
func dismissSearch() {
    searchBar.text = ""
    view.endEditing(true)
    tagSearchResults = [Tag]()
    TagSearchFeed?.collectionView.reloadData()
    searchResultsContainer.isHidden = true
    hideSearchBar() 
}



func showSearchBar() {
    searchBar.alpha = 0
    navigationItem.titleView = searchBar
    let cancelButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Cancel", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(searchBarCancelButtonClicked))
    cancelButton.tintColor = .white
    navigationItem.setRightBarButton(cancelButton, animated: true)
    navigationItem.setLeftBarButton(nil, animated: true)
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {
        self.searchBar.alpha = 1
    }, completion: { finished in
        self.searchBar.becomeFirstResponder()
    })
    self.searchResultsContainer.isHidden = false
}

func hideSearchBar() {
    navigationItem.setRightBarButton(self.searchButton, animated: true)
    navigationItem.setLeftBarButton(self.menuButton, animated: true)
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: {
        self.navigationItem.titleView = nil
    }, completion: { finished in

    })

}

@objc func searchBarCancelButtonClicked() {
    dismissSearch()
}
```

How could I fix these issues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out those bar buttons item were nil, I changed the outlets to strong, and now it works.
From:

```
@IBOutlet var weak searchButton: UIBarButtonItem!
@IBOutlet var weak menuButton: UIBarButtonItem!
```

To:

```
@IBOutlet var searchButton: UIBarButtonItem!
@IBOutlet var menuButton: UIBarButtonItem!
```